# Java | If a=250, b=3, c=(a + b/2)/b * b, Why doesn't c equal 251 but rather 249?

Tags: arithmetic, integers, java

If

```java
int a = 250; 
int b = 3; 
int c = (a + b/2)/b * b;
```

Why doesn't `c` equal 251, but rather 249?
How is it that `c` is smaller than `a` when we are adding?
Doesn't the `divide by b` and `multiply by b` cancel out?

I thought `c= int(250+1.5)=251`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations are executed in order of precedence. When two operations have the same preference, they are evaluated from left to right. In your specific case:

- `b/2` is evaluated first and it evaluates to $1$ (notice the integer division).
- `a+1` is evaluated next, yielding $251$.
- `251/b` is next, yielding $83$.
- Finally, `83*b` evaluates to $249$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's discuss your confusion with precedence and associativity.

Among all the operators Parentheses has highest precedence. That's why $()$ is evaluated first. And then inside $()$ we see two operators $+$ and $/.$ Consequently $/$ has highest precedence than $+$ operator. That's why $/$ is evaluated first then $+$. Now $()$ is completed.

Now we have two operators $/$ and $*$, both have same precedence. Now what is evaluated first between two? Here now you use the associativity to break the tie. $/$ and $*$ uses left to right associativity$($which is known as left associativity$).$ That why $/$ is evaluated first because it is  at left most operator. And then $*.$

N. B:- For two $\uparrow,$ the associativity right to left means follows right associativity.